# run-vcpkg and run-cmake in github actions: The system cannot find the path specified on windows only

Tags: c++, cmake, github-actions, vcpkg

I try to make a new setup using github actions with CMake and vcpkg. All the configurations are working except the windows one. A strange error occurs and I'm not sure why it happens and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
► Run lukka/run-cmake@v3
tool: D:\a\_temp\909795809\cmake-3.21.1-windows-x86_64\bin\cmake.exe
tool: D:\a\_temp\909795809\ninja.exe
► Setup environment variables for triplet 'x64-windows' using 'vcpkg env'
⏱ elapsed: 2.161 seconds
Error: get_directories_non_recursive(D:\a\kangaru\kangaru\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\tools): The system cannot find the path specified.



    at CMakeUtils.<anonymous> (D:\a\_actions\lukka\run-cmake\v3\dist\index.js:4765:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\a\_actions\lukka\run-cmake\v3\dist\index.js:4717:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: run-cmake action execution failed: 'Error: get_directories_non_recursive(D:\a\kangaru\kangaru\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\tools): The system cannot find the path specified.
```

My workflow file is the following:

```
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    env:
      buildDir: ${{ github.workspace }}/build
    name: ${{ matrix.os }}-hosted-basic
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]
        include:
          - os: windows-latest
            triplet: x64-windows
            build-type: RelWithDebInfo
          - os: ubuntu-latest
            triplet: x64-linux
            build-type: RelWithDebInfo
          - os: macos-latest
            triplet: x64-osx
            build-type: RelWithDebInfo
            
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: get-cmake
        uses: lukka/get-cmake@v3.21.1

      - name: Run vcpkg
        uses: lukka/run-vcpkg@v6
        with:
          # Just install vcpkg for now, do not install any ports in this step yet.
          setupOnly: true
          # Location of the vcpkg as submodule of the repository.
          vcpkgDirectory: '${{ github.workspace }}/vcpkg'
          vcpkgGitCommitId: '57bd7102d9fd880daa1b0958692294c4a125f6d8'
          # Since the cache must be invalidated when content of the vcpkg.json file changes, let's
          # compute its hash and append this to the computed cache's key.
          appendedCacheKey: ${{ hashFiles( '**/vcpkg.json' ) }}
          vcpkgTriplet: ${{ matrix.triplet }}
          # Ensure the vcpkg artifacts are cached, they are generated in the 'CMAKE_BINARY_DIR/vcpkg_installed'.
          additionalCachedPaths: ${{ env.buildDir }}/vcpkg_installed
      - name: 'Run CMake with Ninja, install dependencies with vcpkg, build with CMake'
        uses: lukka/run-cmake@v3
        with:
          cmakeListsOrSettingsJson: CMakeListsTxtBasic
          cmakeListsTxtPath: '${{ github.workspace }}/CMakeLists.txt'
          useVcpkgToolchainFile: true
          cmakeAppendedArgs: '-GNinja -DKANGARU_TEST=ON'
          buildDirectory: ${{ env.buildDir }}

      - name: Test
        working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/build
        # Execute tests defined by the CMake configuration.  
        # See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html for more detail
        run: ctest -C ${{env.build-type}}
```

I mostly followed the [run-vcpkg quickstart guide](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-vcpkg#quickstart).

You can check the [live error here](https://github.com/gracicot/kangaru/runs/3283002476?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: You should probably open this as an issue with `lukka` on GitHub...

Comment: Yeah, I figured it could be an issue on their side, so I opened [this one here](https://github.com/lukka/run-cmake/issues/54).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been reported here and it has been fixed: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/19552

Context: when `run-cmake` launches CMake on Windows with the vcpkg toolchain, unless CC/CXX env vars are already defined, the environment is setup for the MSVC toolset by running the `vcpkg env --triplet <triplet>` command.

Unfortunately this command got broken in vcpkg aftert his [commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/commit/dee2b65c7c565697d38b74f26534e62d1f502a89), and when invoked it fails with what you reported:

```
Error: get_directories_non_recursive(D:\a\path\\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\tools): 
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Using a vcpkg repository Git commit more recent than [e52d3b24cb45d1e5c8a6eddcce1b12bf570608da](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/20105/commits/e52d3b24cb45d1e5c8a6eddcce1b12bf570608da) contains the fix.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2022 the command:
`vcpkg integrate install` just works in Github Actions environment.
For example see my [GitHub](https://github.com/vSzemkel/Manam/blob/master/.github/workflows/msbuild.yml)